# GitHub Push Event All Commits

Tags: github, github-api

According to the GitHub API Events Page for the [Push Event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) it returns an array of `commits`. It says the following:

> The array includes a maximum of 20 commits. If necessary, you can use the [Commits API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/) to fetch additional commits.

Only problem is when looking at the Commits API there is no way to get the commits linked to a specific `Push Event`.

Running a `GET` HTTP request for the URL: https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/commits?sha=commitsha seems to return all the commits before that `sha`. I'm just looking to somehow get the commits that were pushed in that specific `Push Event`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just looking to somehow get the commits that were pushed in that specific `Push Event`.

If you read the `head` and `before` identifiers from the event payload, you can then [compare two commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits) to get up to 250 commits in this range:

```
GET  https://api.github.com/repos/{owner|/{repo}/compare/{before}...{head}
```

The API response from that endpoint contains lots of additional information, but the `commits` array is what you are looking for.